# CREDIT DEBIT transaction update balance accordingly mysql trigger

Tags: mysql

I have two tables those are shown in below table one is for transactions and another one is to keep the balance of the transactions the transaction types are credit and debit whenever there is a credit transaction the balance table should be added with the amount and whenever there is a debit transaction the balance table should subtract that amount from it. How will I do that? using MySQL triggers the tables are shown on the below fiddle.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/73eabbc

Comment: This is trivial , are you having a specific problem, if so publish your code and tell us what the problem is.

Comment: I dont need two triggers i just wanted a single trigger once the system is running the wallet query which is like this 'INSERT into wallet_transactions(uuid,amount,transaction_type,card_payment_uuid) VALUES(?,?,?,?)' I need the update of the balance to be happen that could be either creadit or may be debit